# Norfolk Island Aussie citizen status when entering the USA

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, australian-citizens, norfolk-island

[Norfolk Island](https://maps.app.goo.gl/8teFAahRWFfmPgA88) is a territory between* Australia and New Zealand.  Up until 2016 it was self-governing, however in the middle of that year Australia changed its status, and most Australian laws now also cover the territory as well.

We have a young Norfolk friend coming to visit soon, who we told would need to get an ESTA authorization in order to enter the US on the way to us.

However, because of Norfolk Island's territory status, I felt it prudent to double-check whether ESTA would be the required document, or does the US consider Norfolk Island as somehow different to Australia (as most Norfolk Islanders do) and have other requirements?

They travel with an Australian passport, however I don't know for certain whether there aren't any limitations on this for Norfolk Islanders.

---

<sup>*Yes I know "between" Aussie and NZ isn't entirely accurate, but it was the easiest way to describe it</sup>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the purposes of ESTA/VWP what matters is the persons citizenship.  As you've stated they hold an Australian Passport, they are an Australian citizen and thus eligible to apply for an ESTA and enter the US using the Visa Waiver Program (presuming the ESTA is approved).

During the ESTA application they will be asked their address, in which case if Norfolk Island is listed as a country they can select that, otherwise they would select the country of Australia.

Comment: Norfolk Island is indeed listed as a country of birth in the ESTA application.

Comment: It is part of the Federal Electorate of Bean, along with the bottom of the ACT salamander. It is considered part of NSW for administrative purposes. Citizenship matters, in terms of Country of Birth, it would still equate to Australia.